# Why I have this artefacts when I texturing my model?

Tags: texturing, uv, baking

problem:
[image]

my UV unwrap of top part of hourglass maked in blender:
[image]

download 3d model:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ri5GdgyilFbvaRLdfPjSJim_0hSTmbNh/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have indicated in your post that you send this to Substance Painter.

The issue here is that, Substance Painter on a per-material basis. So each object sharing the same material will use the same maps. So, technically, your UV's from SP look like this:

[image: actual UVs]

So you have to either arrange the UVs to make them fit the UV space without overlapping. Or you have to seperate into different materials.